# Copy Pose and Copy Inverted Pose Buttons

Tags: dopesheet, pose-mode

I'm following a Blender book on character creation. It mentions about clicking on Copy Pose and Paste Inverted Pose buttons on the header. I'm guessing it's referring to on the Dope Sheet, which I have open in a separate partition. Either way, I'm not seeing those buttons anywhere and the buttons I thought were them don't do the job properly, but copy/paste the keyframes to the copy/paste buffer.

Do these buttons exist? If so, where are they?

Thanks.

Comment: Please always search [the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/armatures/posing/editing.html#copy-paste-pose) first.

Comment: See, I thought those were the buttons, but whenever I click on the Paste Inverted Pose button, the model poses weirdly. However, if I use Shift, Ctrl + Z, it poses correctly.

Comment: It would help if you included your research in the question and document how "*the model poses weirdly*". (It's not supposed to pose weirdly.)